# Cross validation accuracy improved, while test accuracy went down

Tags: r, cross-validation, random-forest

I did two submissions to Kaggle's Titanic competition. In both models I used Random Forest with Caret's cross validation.

During the first run, according to CV, by best model scored 82% accuracy and RF's OOB error was 15%. With Kaggle's hidden data I scored 0.79%.

Later, I added a new predictor to my model and run the whole thing again. CV gave me 83%, RF's OOB gave me 14% (both improved by 1%), but when I submitted to Kaggle I got a lower score of 0.77%.

Now, I assume I had an overfit with the second model thus scored lower in Kaggle, but why the cross validation's accuracy did the opposite?

Comment: Actually you answered your own question: your models were overfitting. After adding a new feature, your models became more overfitting, thus the estimated accuracy was higher in cross validation but lower in actual testing.